# Is there a way to stop this default insert in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so i have this data structure

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :positions

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :users, :through => :positions

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id, :regular_user
end
```

And my database structure

```
create_table "positions", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
  t.boolean  "regular_user", :default => true
end
```

And if i add another company to a users companies, the regular_user flag is always set to true

```
1.9.3-p125 :013 > @user.companies << Company.last
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` 
  ORDER BY `companies`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `positions` 
(`company_id`, `created_at`, `regular_user`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) 
VALUES 
(263, '2012-07-25 13:56:56', 1, '2012-07-25 13:56:56', 757)
```

Is there a way to set the flag to false before the insert

I have been getting around it by doing this....which is hackish

```
@user.positions.update_all(:regular_user => false) if @user.is_admin?
```

Is there another way (cleaner) to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `before_save` filter.
Ex.:

```
class Position

  before_save :set_regular_user_to_false

  def set_regular_user_to_false
    self.regular_user = false
  end

end
```

Like the filter name says, this will intercept the chain of events right before saving the `position` object, so you can change the `regular_user` attribute.

**EDIT**

```
def set_regular_user_to_false
  if self.user.user_type != 'admin'
    self.regular_user = false
  end
  true
end
```

Comment: how do i call that from  `@user.companies << Company.last`

Comment: some users need to be set to true and some set to false....not everybody is false...only admins

Comment: You can put aditional logic in the filter method. Like checking the user_type and set the regular user to true or false.

Comment: You don't need to call the filter, it will apply by itself.

Comment: you dont have access to the user type in the position model

Comment: current_user is not available

Comment: Well, if a position belongs_to an user, then you have access to self.user.user_type, or whatever it is called, inside the filter. I will edit with an example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14406/discussion-between-matt-and-murifox)

Comment: Added true to the end of the before_filter because they need to return true or false

Answer (score 1):

You can directly insert a position

```
user.positions << Position.new(company: Company.last, regular_user: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly its been a while since I've used AR migrations so double check my syntax before you run this on a production database.

Having said that, this is being set on a database level as your table structure has that set to true. So if a NULL situation exists it will be made true.

You should be able to run a migration that will change your database column to default to false. You can also override with a callback as @MurifoX suggests, but I think this better addresses your core complaint.

Good Luck!

```
class ChangePostitionsRegularUser < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    change_column :positions, :regular_user, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def down
    change_column :positions, :regular_user, :boolean, :default => true
  end
end
```

Comment: the better syntax is     change_column_default(:positions, :regular_user, nil)