# Why is the before filter giving me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my data structure

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :positions

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :users, :through => :positions

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id, :regular_user
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id, :regular_user
  before_save :set_regular_user

  def set_regular_user
    if self.user.is_admin?
      self.regular_user = false
    else
      self.regular_user = true
    end
  end
end
```

everytime i run

```
@user.companies << Company.last
```

I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`

but if i remove my before filter everthing works out perfect and it saves as expected

```
 @user.companies << Company.last
     Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` ORDER BY `companies`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
      (0.1ms)  BEGIN
     SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `positions` (`company_id`, `created_at`, `regular_user`, `updated_at`, `user_id`)
      VALUES 
      (263, '2012-07-25 14:44:15', NULL, '2012-07-25 14:44:15', 757)
```

Any ideas what i am missing ....this question is based on this earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651489/is-there-a-way-to-stop-this-default-insert-in-rails/11651629#11651629)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks need to return true in order to continue, false cancels the operation.  In your function, the value of the if statement may be false: `self.regular_user = false`   The return value of a ruby function is the last statement.

Just add a return true to the end.

Answer (score 1):

As @DGM says, it is good practice for callbacks to always return true at the end (or false at some point in the flow if they should prevent the code continuing). Otherwise it can be the source of some very odd bugs further down the line (speaking from experience :) ).

I suspect it is the if branch returning the false. Hopefully if you just add true as the last statement in the callback it should work.